# Bind Textblock text to 2 different properties

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview, textblock

I have a binded treeview that displays one of the properties (namely, the displayname) of the treeviewitem (which are custom viewmodel's of an object).

Here is the associated xaml:

```
<local:ExtendedTreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubOrganLocations}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding OrganDisplayName}" >
                        </TextBlock>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </local:ExtendedTreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

What I want is to be able to display another property next to the display name in parenthesis.

so instead of the treeview looking like this:

```
Root
-sub node1
--subsub node1
-sub node2
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Root (Type1)
    -sub node1 (Type2)
    --subsub node1 (Type 3)
    -sub node2 (Type 1)
```

How can I accomplish this? Using multi-binding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TextBlock>
   <TextBlock.Text>
      <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} ({1})">
          <Binding Path="{YourBindingHere}" />
          <Binding Path="{YourBindingHere}" />
      </MultiBinding>
   </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of this as I've not done much WPF, more silverlight and it's only available as a 3rd party control in silverlight. This is a better solution than mine (so long as it works, which I can't prove or disprove)

Comment: I can guarantee it works, I'm using it in several places in a very large WPF application that I'm currently developing.

Comment: Yeah, I believe you, I just wanted to cover my ass a bit in the comment. Saying it's a better solution than mine is fairly definitive considering that I haven't actually tried it. I just didn't want the OP to be able to come back and say "BenCr, you said this was better and it wasn't". Sorry for any offense.

Comment: @BenCR None taken, just reassuring the OP.

Comment: @Erno According to the MSDN documentation you can make them TwoWay, however I've never done that so I don't know how it would work.

Comment: I'd expect a TextBox to be TwoWay. In this case it is a TextBlock so no worries. I was just curious. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use multiple text blocks

```
<local:ExtendedTreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubOrganLocations}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding OrganDisplayName}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TypeName}" />
        </Grid>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</local:ExtendedTreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

Or you could add a property to your view model which calculate the full name internally and just bind to that.

Answer (score 0):

Or use `<Run/>`:

```
<TextBlock>
  <Run Text="{Binding OrganDisplayName}"/>
  <Run Text=" ("/>
  <Run Text="{Binding TypeName}"/>
  <Run Text=")"/>
</TextBlock>
```